# how pass png image generated in controller to a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display an image (PNG) generated in controller, which is not saved in a file. Is it possible to pass such generated image data to view? I did a bit of googling, but not found anything on this idea. A similar solution is provided here: [Invalid encoding with rqrcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223060/invalid-encoding-with-rqrcode), saving image in temporary file and assigning it back, but I am trying to avoid this extra step.

I tried to use `send_data disposition: 'inline'` but I am stuck how to use this object in my view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at data URIs.  That might solve what you're looking for.

[The wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples) even has an example for PNGs.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to load an image's data inline using [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and Base 64 encoding:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,/<%= @image_data_b64 %>" />
```

You can then use [ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveSupport/Base64.encode64) to encode the image data:

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raw_data = # Code to get image data as string
    @image_data_b64  = ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(raw_data)
  end
end
```

Comment: Good tip, but encode64 is not included in Rails 4 anymore. I used Ruby Std-Lib `Base64.encode64`